# Atualizar Jframe

Tags: java, swing

Fiz um software para monitorar servidores

Tenho um `Jframe` com vários botões em que esses setam uma cor (verde se servidor esta online e vermelho caso contrario). Faço esse teste usando *ping*.

Quando clico no botão para abrir esse frame, todos os botões são pintados uma única vez, gostaria de fazer isso para ficar atualizando em tempo real

Meu codigo inicia assim:

```
 private void BtTecnicoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                          
    JFramePrincipal d = new JFramePrincipal();
    d.setVisible(true);


    PingThread servidor = new PingThread ("ip",d.BTbotao);
    servidor.start();
}
```

Onde eu usaria o `repaint` ou `revalidate` caso fosse necessário usa-los?

Answer (score 1):

Quando faz o ping actualiza a JFrame. Se estiver online pinta verde e faz:

```
botao.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

Se estiver offline:

```
botao.setBackground(Color.RED);
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```